# Tools and Libs to be a more productive .net web developer

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to get a list together of tools/libraries that make me more productive or more efficient.

Tools I am using at this moment are ELMAH for all my logging or errors and exceptions.

I am also using the JQuery validation library and been playing with xVal lately.

I know there are similar posts, but they are very broad, i am looking for more specific .Net web dev tools & libs.

Commercial and non commercial tools are all welcome.

What else should i be trying that I have missed.

Regards

Ian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this regard, its worth mentioning [Scott Hanselmans Ultimate Developer and Power Users Tool List](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ScottHanselmans2009UltimateDeveloperAndPowerUsersToolListForWindows.aspx).

Comment: Now that is a great list. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).

A must for every web dev, including .NET. Of course this includes similar tools in other browsers like the IE Developer Toolbar and Chrome's built-in tools.